# Getting error of failed to fetch at client side

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I recently started MERN stack and i am doing user auth

while trying to run signup functionality in my app i am getting error of failed to fetch.
here is my code:
Server side

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const { default: mongoose } = require("mongoose");
const User = require('./models/user.models')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const app = express();

const PORT = 1337

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/user-auth')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name, email, password } = req.body
    
        const newPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
    
        const user = await User.create({
            name,
            email,
            password: newPassword
        })
    
        if(!user){
            throw new Error('Something went wrong')
        }
    
        return res.status(200).json(user, {status: 200, msg: 'user created'})
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({msg: error})
    }
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`app listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

User model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const User = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true },
        quote: { type: String },
    },
    { collection: 'user-data' }
)

const model = mongoose.model('UserData', User)

module.exports = model
```

Client side app.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  async function registerUser(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name,
        email,
        password
      })
    })

    const data = await response.json()
    if(data.status === 200){
      console.log("Registered successfully");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form onSubmit={registerUser}>
        <input 
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
        />[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pUn9.png)
        <input 
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email"
        />
        <input 
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <input type='submit' value={'Register'} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

From what i got on google its error on client side so i am providing error screenshots as well
[Actual error on client side with network failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIqVH.png)
[log of that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FECa.png)

Help me solve this, mainly as a new mern stack dev help me understand what is needed here in this type of situations

Comment: Have you enabled ```cors``` on your server? Link to the npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Here are few suggestions that you could take, to debug this code.
1. Insert try catch block in registerUser function, this would help you to run you application even when you encounter some error. 
2. You should try to implement proxy inorder to avoid cors error, as I can see you are running frontend at 3000 and backend at 1337. Search react proxy and implement that.
I guess setting up proxy with solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Error is throwing beacuse of import and export of file

In Your Schema File

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const User = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true },
        quote: { type: String },
    },
    { collection: 'user-data' }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserData', User)
```

and import User schema like this in your required file;

`const User = require('./models/user')`